# How do I change sample rate of 16-bit PCM audio from 24000 Hz to 48000 Hz in Rust?

Tags: audio, rust, resampling, pcm

I'm getting 16-bit PCM data (24000 Hz) from Google's text to speech service which is then stored in a u8 array. Is there a simple way of resampling this to 48000 Hz with the output being a u8 array? I don't understand any of the examples online on FFmpeg.

Right now I wrapped it in a Cursor to read each i16 individually and then duplicating each of them once (i.e. so that 1234 becomes 11223344). My logic is that since the original audio is 24000, then doubling that makes it 48000, right?

```
let mut raw = Cursor::new(raw);
let mut new_samples = Vec::new();

loop {
    match raw.read_i16::<LittleEndian>() {
        Ok(x) => {
            samples.push(x);
            samples.push(x);
        }
        Err(_) => break,
    }
}
```

Next I used the hound crate to convert the new samples to a 48000 WAV.

```
let mut new_wav = Cursor::new(Vec::new());
let mut writer = WavWriter::new(
    &mut new_wav,
    WavSpec {
        channels: 1,
        sample_rate: 48000,
        bits_per_sample: 16,
        sample_format: SampleFormat::Int,
    },
)
.unwrap();

new_samples
    .into_iter()
    .for_each(|x| writer.write_sample(x).unwrap());

writer.finalize().unwrap();
```

Now new_wav should have the 48000 Hz audio. This doesn't work though. I just hear a really brief static when I play it using the Discord songbird crate:

```
call.lock().await.play_source(Input::new(
    false,
    new_wav.into_inner().into(),
    Codec::Pcm,
    Container::Raw,
    None,
));
```

Comment: Which crate are you using? Could you show us what your code looks like so far?

Comment: @Locke I use hound and songbird (for Discord)

Comment: I do not know anything about working with audio, but it sounds like the [samplerate crate](https://crates.io/crates/samplerate) is compatible with `hound` and can convert the audio for you.

Comment: You're writing data as a wav, but you attempt to play it as raw… Try writing it to a file and playing it with your favorite media player.

Comment: Duplicating the samples like you do should work but will add some high frequency noise (>12kHz). If you don't want to add an external dependency, you could generate new samples by [averaging consecutive samples](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=e27cc5a41343465a0725ca912c9983c3).

Comment: @Jmb Okay, I'll do that. I can't upvote your comment but thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured it out. This is how I did it.

```
let mut original = Cursor::new(original);
let mut resampled = Cursor::new(Vec::new());

loop {
    match original.read_i16::<LittleEndian>() {
        Ok(x) => {
            // Write it twice
            resampled.write_i16::<LittleEndian>(x).unwrap();
            resampled.write_i16::<LittleEndian>(x).unwrap();
        }
        Err(_) => break,
    }
}
```

Now "resampled" is 48000 Hz (and it plays perfectly).